# unable to create filter and directives in angular fullstack project

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular, angular-fullstack

I am using angular-fullstack yeoman generator and added some dependencies to my bower.json. I have then `sudo npm install` and `bower install`. Now when I run the command `yo angular-fullstack:directive simple` or `yo angular-fullstack:filter propsFilter` I get the below error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'file-utils'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:11:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling (maybe uninstall/reinstall).

Given your trace, it looks like `npm install` broke and didn't install dependencies correctly. I've had this issue a lot switching to npm 3 and running install/update command over a previously installed package.

Comment: how to reinstall npm. I am using npm 3.4.0 version